# Google Directory API setPassword() Java

Tags: java, api, admin

I need help about Google directory API. I follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/java) and every works well, I mean that i have the list of the users. But I want that my application updates a password user.

I just complete the code of the file DirectoryQuickStart.java with:

```
User u = users.get(3);
String password = "NewPassword";
u.setPassword(password);
service.users().update(u.getId(),u).execute();
```

You must read the tutorial to understand :) I have a problem during the compilation: Insufficient Permission error 403:

http://postimg.org/image/4gxuli8b5/

I think this problem is in the developper console or in the security parameter in the admin console... I don't understand

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be that you have not included the scope for updating users which is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user in your request. Go To Google Directory API reference and from Try It, check if an update for password works from there.  The link is [this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update)